# Greedy most diverse subset of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, greedy

This is my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

A = ['A','B','C']
M = ['1','2','3']
F = ['plus','minus','square']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(A,M,F)), columns=['A','M','F'])
print(df)


   A  M       F
0   A  1    plus
1   A  1   minus
2   A  1  square
3   A  2    plus
4   A  2   minus
5   A  2  square
```

I want to get the top-n rows (subset) from that dataframe which maximum diverse. 
To compute diversity, I used `1- jaccard`.

```
def jaccard(a, b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))
```

By using dataframe operation, I can do a cartesian product to that dataframe using `apply` and compute the diversity values of each pair, and get the max value of diversity each pair by using `df.idxmax(axis=1)`. But in here I have to compute all diversity values of each pair first which is not efficient.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   0.0 1.0 0.8 0.5 0.5 0.8 0.5 1.0 0.8 0.8 0.8
1   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.8 1.0 0.8 1.0 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.8 0.8 1.0 1.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.5 0.8 0.5
4   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.8 0.8 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.8

df.idxmax(axis=1).sample(4)
5    6
2    3
0    1
8    9
dtype: int64
```

I want to implement this algorithm, but in some how, I did not understand the lines : 6 and 7.

[image]

How to compute argmax in here? and why in the line 10, it returns Sk but there is no initiation Sk value inside the looping?

Comment: S_k is initiated outside the loop as a random element `x`, see line 1 through 3. However, what is the function `d`?

Comment: d is diversity, which is `1-similarity`. so, is the element of S_k equal to S_i on the final result?

Comment: Well, i = k after the while loop, so yes. Line 7 essentially appends the `x_max` value found in line 6 to the set in the given loop. However, I too am having difficult understanding line 6.